Why can't C++ concepts use a simple requirement to check if a nested type exists?
template <typename T>
concept HasInner = requires { T::inner; };

void foo(HasInner auto x) { return; }
struct Test { using inner = int; };

int main()
{
    foo(Test());
}

Why can't this code be compiled？ Is T::inner; not a valid expression?
I know concept HasInner = requires { typename T::inner; }; is ok. But I want know why the first one is not ok.
Thank you, everyone. I got it.
T::inner is invalid, because of a type name like int is not a expression.
So, HasInner is satisfied when T::inner is a expression.
struct Test { constexpr int static inner = 1; };
int main()
{
    foo(Test()); // This code can be compiled correctly.
}


"Is inner_type::type; not a valid expression?": I assume you mixed up some names here. There is no inner_type or type in your code. Assuming you mean what I think you mean: No, it is not a valid expression. Suppose you wrote Test::inner; as a statement in the body of main. Do you expect that to be valid and if so, what should it mean?

Test::inner in the body of main is useless, but it is valid.

Have you tried it? (https://godbolt.org/z/d9437orsr) It is not valid. It is neither an expression nor a complete declaration.

Sorry, inner_type is a mistake

You are right, I only test it with clang and msvc, only a warning. Maybe it not supported by standard.

Even if the compilers only warn: The warning will tell you that they interpret it as incomplete declaration, not as expression. Test::inner can be a type-specifier in a declaration and it can be a type-id in a cast expression of the form (Test::inner)E where E is an expression or it can be a simple-type-specifier in a functional cast expression of the form Test::inner(E) where E is an expression, but Test::inner itself is not an expression, it is always a type.

(Note that in C++ types are not first-class. An expression can't have a type as result, only a value.) (And also, yes, a declaration that doesn't declare anything is ill-formed according to the standard, meaning that a compiler has to warn about it at least and that the standard doesn't require the compiler to behave in any particular way otherwise, but that isn't relevant here.)

Sorry, my English is not well. I confused the concepts of the two. I think I should have understood. Thank you, You are an excellent C++ expert.@user17732522


I know concept HasInner = requires { typename T::inner; }; is ok. But I want know why the first one is not ok.

Because requires{ T::inner; } expects T::inner to not be a type (but rather a variable or a function). I'm not sure what answer you expected.
It wouldn't be very useful to make T::inner accept both types and non-types.

I don't want to make T::inner accept both types and non-types. But I think T::inner is a valid expression, so compiler should accept it, because of simple requirement only needs the expr is valid.

@youz a) You're precisely asking for T::inner to accept both types and non-types b) a type name is not an expression, e.g. int is not an expression.

"I don't want to make T::inner accept both types and non-types." requires { typename T::inner; } or requires { T::inner; };.

@Jarod42 @Passer By Thank you, I got it.
a) type name is not an expr, so it is invalid.
b) T::inner is accepted when inner is a expr, e.g static constexpr inner int value = 1;

@youz https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

This isn't really about concepts, it's a templating error that would apply to templated classes and functions as well.
When you specialize on T and want to use T::something, you need typename because it's a dependent name.
edit
Per the comment from @user17732522, this usage of typename is more specialized than the general case. For more, look at Type Requirements.

That's not really true in this instance. typename here is part of the requirement syntax. It is not the usual typename of a typename-specifier used in other contexts. The requirement behaves differently than a requirement that doesn't start with typename.
